Determinant test for stability of a matrix
This is a challenge question from Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang in the chapter about determinants. Given $|\det(A)|>1$, how can I prove that the powers $A^n$ cannot stay bounded? I sort have the intuition that if $|\det(A)|>1$ then multiplying by A can only increase the matrix getting multiplied, but I don't think I have reached the key here.

Any help is appreciated!

If $|A^n|$ grows without bound, then the same must be true for the entries of $A^n$

Matrices with bounded entries have bounded determinants. So if the determinant is not bounded, then ...

Ah I see how the product rule comes in! Thanks for the explanation!

Looking at the comments, you've already received enough help to get the intuition needed to explain why this is true. I just wish to add the following:
I believe (if my memory serves me right) in the Determinants chapter of Strang's book he introduces you to the following identity: $(\det(A))^n = \det(A^n)$
So it would be nice if you could use it here.
If we have $|\det(A)| > 1$, then continuously multiplying the determinant, we will obviously get an unbounded result. so if $(\det(A))^n$ increases infinitely, then so must $\det(A^n)$, because according to the identity, they're equal. But if $\det(A^n)$  grows in magnitude, then the values in the matrix have to grow too!
